# `finally` and masking asynchronous exceptions

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, exception

I still can't wrap my head around masking asynchronous exceptions.

`finally` in `Control.Exception` masks the action:

```hs
a `finally` sequel =
  mask $ \restore -> do
    r <- restore a `onException` sequel
    _ <- sequel
    return r
```

What difference would it make if `finally` internally doesn't mask?

```hs
a `finally` sequel = do
  r <- a `onException` sequel
  _ <- sequel
  return r
```

Answering this question would help me understand masking asynchronous exceptions. I still can't relate to it quite well.

Answer (score 1):

The intent of a `finally` block is that the `sequel` is executed no matter what. If `a` is interrupted by an asynchronous exception, then `sequel` is executed. What if `sequel` is interrupted by the exception? Or the exception is raised just between `a` and `sequel`? Then `sequel` still needs to finish running.

Therefore asynchronous exceptions are masked in `a finally sequel` except while running `a` itself. Thus `sequel` will be fully executed if the exception is raised at any time during the execution of `a finally sequel`. Only `a` can be interrupted by the exception.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.
My problem was that I misinterpreted what an asynchronous exception means. It could be something like a user's interrupt. I could mask it so that the user's interrupt doesn't interrupt the program if I want to:

```
run1 = mask $ \restore ->
  restore $ forever $ putStrLn "meow"

run2 = mask $ \_ ->
  forever $ putStrLn "meow"
```

run1 can be interrupted using the user's interrupt exception, while that is not possible with run2.
That's because the prevailing masking state in run1 is restored. But in run2 is not restored